# How to get the unique result sets using hibernate 4.1

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Here is my table structure in mysql having Entity Name `Extension`.
I want to get all the unique `extcat` in my result set using `hibernate 4.1`.
Like `extcat(image, word)`.

How to get this.

```
| extid | extName | extcat
---------------------------
   1    |   jpg   | image
   2    |   jpg   | image
   3    |   doc   | word
   4    |   dcx   | word
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Criteria:-

```
Criteria cr = getCurrentSession().createCritiera(Extension.class) 
.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
.add(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("extcat")))
.add(Projections.property("extid"), "extid")
.add(Projections.property("extName"), "extName"))
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Extension.class));
List<Extension> list = cr.list();
```

Comment: Some sort of type conversion issue 'cast argument 1 to criterion'. for Projections.distinct(Projections.property("extcat"))

Comment: @zahidKhan i didn't understand the question , do you need all the data to be distinct ?

Comment: Sorry, You are spot. Removed my comment.

Comment: the return type is List<Extension> but when getting values with getter it shows java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.myApp.models.Extension. Why???

Comment: @ZahidKhan this error because the criteria meant to return `List<String>` of unique **extcat ** , i made an update check it out :))

Comment: Too Good now every thing is Clear. Thanks for All this

Answer (score 0):

Make use of Criteria feature in Hibernate for getting the unique resultsets.

Comment: This is no answer - as long as you don't provide an example for the specific question or add some more details.